# Получение данные ответа от сервера и передать на другую страницу

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router-dom

На ParentPage.js Пытаюсь получать ответа от адреса https://randomuser.me/api, и потом передать id на другую страницу ChildPage чтобы в дальнейшем использовать этот id или отправить еще запрос через ChildPage. И проблема в том что не могу получить данные на ChildPage? Скажите где я что то пропустил или вообще правильно ли делаю?

ParentPage.js:

```
      const getResponse= () => {
        const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

           axios.get(url)
           .then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
          setResponse(res.data.page.id)
          navigate('/child', {state: {response}});
           })
           .catch((error) => {
               console.log(error);
           });
    };
```

ChildPage.js:

```
export const ChildPage= () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    console.log(location);
    const x = location.state.response

  return (
    <>
    <h1>{x}</h1>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: **setResponse** Что это такое? Сеттер состояния? И что такое **response**? **condt** - Это опечатка?

Comment: @SwaD изменил! да, сеттер состояния.

Comment: Изменение состояния, это асинхронная операция. Измените `{state: {response}}` на `res.data.page.id`